# Premature end of file Error

Tags: java, xslt, transformer-model

I am using XSL to configure my XML file into a smaller XML. My code fragments are so:

```
public class MessageTransformer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer (new StreamSource("sample.xsl"));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource ("sample.xml"),  
            new StreamResult( new FileOutputStream("sample.xml"))
        );
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }    
}   
}
```

I got this error

```
ERROR:  'Premature end of file.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Premature end of file.'
```

When I use XSL file to transform XML manually I don' t have any problem. However with this JAVA file I cannot transform.

What would be the problem?

Comment: I get the feeling that having the StreamSource (your original xml) and StreamResult (the result after xslt) point to the same file, could get you in trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are streaming from and to the same file.  Try changing it to something like this:

```
transformer.transform(new StreamSource ("sample.xml"),  
        new StreamResult( new FileOutputStream("sample_result.xml"))
    );
```

Comment: I have just solved by using a different method. But also your offer is true. May be this will be useful for someone else. Thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

Complete your xml file give any tag other wise it will give an error: **Premature end of file.**

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
<Customer>
<person>
    <Customer_ID>1</Customer_ID>
    <name>Nirav Modi</name>
</person>
<person>
    <Customer_ID>2</Customer_ID>
    <name>Nihar dave</name>
</person>
</Customer>
```

Like this and try again.